# Where is the std.all & std.lv information stored in the lavaan object?

Tags: r-lavaan, semplot

Does anyone know where the std.all & std.lv information stored in the lavaan object?

I am attempting a work-around for a semPlot::semPaths issue by replacing the ParTable in one lavaan object with that of another. This work-around succeeds, except for the standardized estimates (ie., std.all & std.lv). I am assuming I have to swap out some other information between the two, but I am not sure where those data are stored in the lavaan object.

Comment: As far as I know, the standardized estaimtes are computed when they are requested. They are not stored.

Comment: If you are working on semPaths(), it already supports labeling edges using standardized estimates. Is your goal setting the (unstandardized) estimates in a lavaan object manually and using semPaths() to label edges using  the implied standardized estimates?

Comment: I should not use "implied" because it is usually used for something else. I meant the standardized estimates computed from the manually set (unstandardized) parameter estimates.